# Order of operations in if statement

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the following if structure

```
ArrayList<String> list;
if(list != null){
      if(list.get(0).equals("value"){
            //do stuff
      }
}
```

is it possible to write this as one if statement? (the second if statement would make no sense if the first if statement results in false, because it would throw NullPointerException)

Comment: use `&&` to combine the conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical operators combine separate conditions together into one statement. These are notably `&&` and `||`, known as `AND` and `OR` respectively, but can fluctuate based on the language. You'd want to use the `AND` operator to say both conditions must be satisfied to run the code within the if, as is your case. The `OR` will run code if either condition is satisfied. So you could write your if's as:

```
if(list != null && list.get(0).equals("value")){
     //do stuff
}
```

To "do stuff" in one line. Mind yourself of short circuit evaluation though. The above statement is not the same as:

```
if(list.get(0).equals("value") && list != null){
     //do stuff
}
```

Due to how most language evaluate conditions (Note that most languages use sce but not all). Languages will evaluate conditions left to right and will only evaluate successive conditions if there is point to it. So if conditions are evaluated as `FALSE && TRUE`, the TRUE will never be evaluated as a FALSE statement has already been encountered making the statement entirely false and not worth wasting further resources. In your case the `list.get(0).equals("value")` will be evaluated first in the second example throwing a possible null pointer, where `list != null` will be run first in the first example, preventing any possible null pointer due to how sce works.

Comment: thanks. was already expecting that it would work like that, but wanted to be safe. ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the && operator

```
ArrayList<String> list;
if(list != null && list.get(0).equals("value"){
    //do stuff

}
```

Comment: @abinmorth yes excatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list != null && list.get(0).equals("value"))
```